# Full-screen Responsize Img - Jquery (very close)

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm referencing [CSS Trick's Full Page Background](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) and using their Jquery method. I want to apply this code to an img that is src inside the HTML, not as a css background. The jquery code works perfectly but I want to add a centering function to the image as the browser view-port is sized down. (Instead of staying top:0; left:0;)

[Here's a link to the site I have this code on](http://oxbowdesigns.com)

What I think is happening is the code is working but the margin never updates when the browser window changes size. Also, when I refresh the page the image goes back to the top left and is no longer centered.

I understand everything in the code but I'm not quite sure how to write a fix. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="backgroundcontainer">

     <img src="images/Homepage/HomepageResize2.jpg" id="bg"  alt="">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.backgroundcontainer{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;   
    background-color:#cea137;   
}

#bg { position: relative; }

.bgwidth { width: 100%; top: 50%; }       
.bgheight { height: 100%; left: 50%; }
```

Jquery:

```
 $(window).ready(function() {    

var theWindow        = $(window);
var   $bg              = $("#bg");
var   aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
var imgWidth = $( window).width() / 2;
var imgHeight = $( window ).height() / 2;   


function resizeBg() {

if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
    $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgheight');
    $('#bg').css("margin", "0 0 0 -" + imgWidth + "px");     // margin-left minus half of width

} else {

    $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgwidth');
    $('#bg').css("margin", "-" + imgHeight + "px 0 0 0");    // margin-top minus half of height
}
}

theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

Comment: Why not use the simple CSS solutions that DO the centering?

Comment: why aren't you using the first css only solution? it works and you don't need to worry about all that jQuery. The jQuery method will probably work on 0.% more users, thats the only pro-jQuery argument that i can think of.

Comment: The simple CSS solution streches and distortes the image.